# GTK EntryCompletion by insertion instead of replacement

Tags: autocomplete, gtk, gtk3

I've built a GTK application with autocompletion in an Entry, but I'd like the selected "completion" string to be replace the only word that the cursor touches, whereas it currently replaces all text in the Entry.

I can use [`set_match_func`](https://ruby-gnome2.osdn.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3AEntryCompletion#set_match_func) on the EntryCompletion to deliver matches based on only the word that is adjacent to the cursor, but I don't see how to override the text-insertion behaviour. Is there a way for me to do this?

I'm working in Ruby with gtk3. *(I linked the doc for gtk2 because for the life of me, I can't find a complete doc for gtk3 in Ruby.)*

**Edit** Here's my implementation (in Ruby), which *lacks* the desired "insert" behaviour:

```rb
module MyAutocomplete
  # Add autocomplete to a Gtk::Entry object
  def self.add entry, &block
    model = Gtk::ListStore.new String
    model.append.set_value 0, 'sd'
    model.append.set_value 0, 'foo'
    model.append.set_value 0, 'six'
    completion = Gtk::EntryCompletion.new
    completion.set_minimum_key_length 0
    completion.set_text_column 0
    completion.set_inline_completion true
    completion.set_model model
    completion.set_match_func do |*args|
      self.match_func *args
    end
    yield(model, completion) if block_given?
    entry.set_completion completion   
  end
  
  def self.match_func(entry_completion, entry_value, list_obj)
    len = 0 # Counts characters into the entry text
    cursor = entry_completion.entry.position
    entry_text = entry_completion.entry.text
    entry_tokens = entry_text.scan(/[\w+@]+|[^\w@]+/)
    current_token = entry_tokens.find { |tok|
      (len += tok.length) >= cursor && tok =~ /\w/
    }
    obj_text = list_obj.get_value(0)
    return current_token && obj_text.start_with?(current_token)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example in **C**?

Comment: @Michi I'm not sure what small example you have in mind because my problem is a non-starter for actually writing any code relevant to insertion. My project is in Ruby, so I've provided my completion-related code above.